# Dynamic search by class name with JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a dynamic search input according to the class names in the I'd like to span tags. However, I am having trouble listing the class name I found. 
**My aim; Displaying the class names matching the value entered in the input into the screen**. Would you help me with this topic?

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
    .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchinput").keyup(function() {
    var inputvalue = $("#searchinput").val();
    var spantags = $("#iconlist span");


    if (inputvalue.length == 0) {
      spantags.show();
    } else {
      if (spantags.hasClass(inputvalue)) {
        $("#iconlist span").hide();
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" placeholder="Ara" id="searchinput" />

<div id="iconlist">
  <span class="test1">Deneme-1</span>
  <span class="test2">Deneme-2</span>
  <span class="test3">Deneme-3</span>
  <span class="test4">Deneme-4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example input to search for?  Do you want to find `1` or must it match `test1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and use something like this to display the span where the class matches the input.

```
spantags.filter(function() {
  return $(this).attr("class").indexOf(inputvalue) > -1;
}).show();
```

**Demo**

```js
jQuery.expr[':'].contains = function(a, i, m) {
  return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase()
    .indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchinput").keyup(function() {
      var inputvalue = $("#searchinput").val();
      var spantags = $("#iconlist span");
      spantags.hide();
      spantags.filter(function() {
        return $(this).attr("class").indexOf(inputvalue) > -1;
      }).show();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" placeholder="Ara" id="searchinput" />

<div id="iconlist">
  <span class="test1">Deneme-1</span>
  <span class="test2">Deneme-2</span>
  <span class="test3">Deneme-3</span>
  <span class="test4">Deneme-4</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you're looking for an exact match, eg "test1" then you cause use

```
spantags.filter(":not(." + inputValue + ")").hide()
```

which says to hide everything that does not have the class you entered
(in the case where you want to match any letter, eg "t", use `.attr("class").indexOf` as in the other answer.

Updated snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchinput").keyup(function() {
    var inputValue = $("#searchinput").val();
    var spantags = $("#iconlist span");

    spantags.show();
    if (inputValue !== "") {
        spantags.filter(":not(." + inputValue + ")").hide()
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search" placeholder="Ara" id="searchinput" />

<div id="iconlist">
  <span class="test1">Deneme-1</span>
  <span class="test2">Deneme-2</span>
  <span class="test3">Deneme-3</span>
  <span class="test4">Deneme-4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support